# Исключение при чтении данных из файла в словарь

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю словарь-поисковик. Есть текстовый файл, в каждой его строке есть первое слово, становящееся ключом к каждому новому элементу класса dictionary и через слэш - содержание элемента.

Пример текста:

*Аббат/1. Настоятель мужского католического монастыря. 2.Католический священнослужитель. II прил. аббатский, -ая,-ое.(все в одной строке)*

КОД

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace КУРСОВАЯ
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(@"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Словарь.txt");
            string line;
            string[] subs;
            line = myReader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                subs = line.Split('/');
                myDictionary.Add(subs[0], subs[1]);
                line = myReader.ReadLine();
            }
         
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            
            string word = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
            word = word.ToUpper();
            if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(word) == true)
            {
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox2.Text +=Environment.NewLine + word + " - " + myDictionary[word];
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine +  " Нет такого слова в словаре" ;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в 33 строке, появляется исключение, гласящее, что индекс находится вне границ, хотя когда я объявлял все сразу, но без while, программа работала

Текст исключения: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Comment: Ошибка значит, что вы обратились к несуществующему элементу массива, например когда в нем 1 элемент или вообще пусто, а вы патаетесь достать второй `[1]`. Используйте отладку, ставьте точку останова и выполняйте код пошагово, смотритн в значнния переменных во время выполнения.

Comment: Заметил у вас такую строку `string word = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);`. Convert.ToString не обязательно здесь использовать. Свойство Text у объекта textBox итак возвращает string. Можно сократить до `string word = textBox1.Text`

Comment: Спасибо, но мою основную проблему с перескакиванием на пустую строку при заполнении dictionary это пока не решило

Comment: @ДаниилБагринцев Добавил ответ с чуть иной реализацией вашего метода и протестировал её. Если ответ помог - поставьте галочку, или задайте вопросы под ним

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю чуток подправить ваш код по загрузке данных в словарь:

```
static void LoadWordsToDictionaryByTextFile(ref Dictionary<string, WordMap> dic, string filePath)
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
    {
        var subs = line.Split('/');
        if (subs.Length <= 1)
            continue;
        var wordMap = new WordMap(subs[0], subs[1]);
        dic.Add(wordMap.Word, wordMap);
    }
}
```

Поиск по словарю:

```
static WordMap TryGetWordMapByWord(Dictionary<string, WordMap> dic, string word) =>
    dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals(word)).Value;
```

Класс WordMap:

```
internal class WordMap
{
    public string Word { get; }

    public string WordMeanings { get; }

    public WordMap(string word, string wordMeanings)
    {
        Word = word;
        WordMeanings = wordMeanings;
    }
}
```

Использовать следующим образом:

```
Dictionary<string, WordMap> wordsDictionary = new();
string filePath = string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"\dictionary.txt");
LoadWordsToDictionaryByTextFile(ref wordsDictionary, filePath);
```

Данные в текстовом файле:

```
Аббат/1. Настоятель мужского католического монастыря. 2.Католический священнослужитель. II прил. аббатский, -ая,-ое.(все в одной строке)
Какое-то слово/1. Какое-то другое определение
```

Данные в словаре лучше хранить в виде класса, а не просто строки. Вообще, старайтесь всегда отстраняться от базовых типов и приходить к классам. Даже, если в классе у вас будет всего-лишь одно свойство - читаемость кода в таком случае в разы увеличится. Никто не будет вас ругать за ещё один класс с 5 строками кода